# Gzip compression or Mod_deflate not working

Tags: plugins, compression

Our wordpress website we need to enable gzip compression we followed below instruction to enabled.

1. we have wp rocket plugin this plugin automatically added compression mode_deflate lines in .htaccess
2. We try to enable from server side so we followed this below article instruction to enable gzip compression
   (https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/how-to-configure-mod_deflate-for-apache-on-centos-7/)

In this article given edit file sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_deflate.conf and paste the below code

```
<filesMatch ".(js|html|txt)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 
    DeflateCompressionLevel 7 
    DeflateMemLevel 8 
    DeflateWindowSize 10
```

we try to do this step we can't save the file when we try to saving file its show 'NO SUCH FILE DIRECTORY'.

and also we tried to edit this file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. This file also can't to save.

Why don't I have a httpd directory?

Comment: None of this is related to WordPress specifically. You'd be better off asking on stackoverflow.com or serverfault.com

Comment: I think it's /etc/apache2 on Ubuntu. Or maybe you're using NGINX not Apache. Try `find /etc -name httpd.conf`.

Comment: Hello Rup, Thanks for your response , I executed above command find / etc -name httpd.conf we getting result /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf